# Symbol Server for Microsoft Edge Chromium

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

apologies if this is the wrong place or format for this question, but I have seen similar questions in the forum. Please point me to another location or formatting and I'd be happy to move my post to accommodate.

My issue is, while trying to troubleshoot an issue with Microsoft Edge, I discovered that there is no symbols for microsoft edge in the msdn symbol server. This caught me completely off-guard:

- Chrome has a symbol server: https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/debugging-on-windows
- Firefox has a symbol server: https://symbols.mozilla.org/
- Chromium's source code is publicly available, so any symbols can be compiled from it. As far as I could find, Edge Chromium does not have its source code publicly available
- All other windows services have their symbols on the msdn symbol server

Can anyone point me to the symbol server for Edge Chromium, or explain how I would develop using it as a platform without having any symbols for it?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find any official documentation about symbol server for Microsoft Edge Chromium. I found [JsDbg](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/JsDbg) in MicrosoftEdge GitHub. It's debugging extensions for Microsoft Edge and other Chromium-based browsers. You could try to use this tool to debug.